# HttpRequest.GetResponse() taking too much time

Tags: c#, performance, http, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have an outlook addin application which I'm connecting with Salesforce.
I'm trying to request some data from SF API which normally returns result in less than 1 second, but with my code It takes from 5-15 seconds to complete.

I have also tried to set proxy to null.

Here is my code:

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
    if (includeCustomHeader == true)
    {
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + ServiceManager.Token.access_token);
        req.Headers.Add("X-PrettyPrint:1");
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
    }
    else
    {
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Proxy = null;

    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);
    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var responseStream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        responseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

     //here it's taking from 5-15 seconds, each request gets a batch of 200 records
    using (var response = req.GetResponse())
    {
        return new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Don't know what am I missing , or could there be any other reason?
Suggestions?

Comment: "I tried many suggestions" isn't helpful. Mention what _exactly_ you did, apart from setting the proxy to null. Do you mean the exact same request takes longer from code than from somewhere else? How does this "somewhere else" differ from your code?

Comment: Start without debugging, wait 30 seconds then call method

Comment: As I've tested further, this line:-  return new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(); runs and returns the result when the result set consist of less than 30 records but when 200 records are requested, it takes too much time. Could it be an issue with ReadToEnd() ?